# Why can't copy data into csv file with double quotes?

Tags: postgresql, copy

The data can be exported with single quote in copy command:

```
COPY mytest TO '/tmp/test.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
COPY 5
```

With double quotes:

```
COPY mytest TO "/tmp/test.csv" DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ""/tmp/test.csv""
LINE 1: COPY mytest TO "/tmp/test.csv" DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
```

It is a strange syntax to limit using double quotes !

Comment: Because that's just the way PostgreSQL was designed?... It's pretty common in most modern RDBMS to use single quotes to define a string literal. Why does it matter to you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a difference between SQL and shell or Perl: in SQL, string literals can only be quoted with single quotes (PostgreSQL also knows “dollar quoting”), while double quotes are exclusively used to surround object names (identifiers).